# Show simple products SKU on product page when the attributes of a configurable product is selected

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, product-page, magento-2.2.1

I'm fairly new to Magento and am currently running Magento 2.2.1. I am looking for a way to have the configurable sku change to the corresponding simple product sku when the configurable products attributes have been selected.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, the *images* and the *price* will change, but **not SKU**.

More information about which elements on the page change when options are selected can be found here: `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()`.

In order to display product SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing **SKU** for each simple product.

Switching **SKU** when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.